# emmet in Visual Studio not working like it did in Sublime

Tags: visual-studio, emmet

I recently switched from Sublime to Visual Studio. Visual Studio has emmet but im wondering how to regain some features that i liked in Sublime.

#### in sublime when you...

type "div" then emmet would write out `<div></div>`

type "pre" then emmet would write out `<pre></pre>`

type "xx" then emmet would write out `<xx></xx>`

type "ng-container" then emmet would write out `<ng-container></ng-container>`

How do i get this back in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue in visual studio and resolved it.

Step-1:

follow steps in url.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate

Step-2:

if it worked cheers

else

it could be issue with select language mode.
on the bottom next of visual studio next to indents select language mode and change it to html.

Thanks & Regards,
Surya kiran.